# Distinct and group by at the same time in LINQ?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, group-by, distinct

Let say I have the following classes:

```
Product { ID, Name }

Meta { ID, Object, Key, Value }

Category { ID, Name }

Relation {ID, ChildID, ParentID } (Child = Product, Parent = Category)
```

and some sample data:

Product:

```
ID   Name

1    Chair
2    Table
```

Meta

```
ID   Object  Key     Value

1      1     Color   "Red"
2      1     Size    "Large"
3      2     Color   "Blue"
4      2     Size    "Small"
```

Category

```
ID   Name

1    Indoor
2    Outdoor
```

Relation

```
ID   ChildID   ParentID

1       1         1
2       1         2
3       2         1
```

Can we use Distinct and Group by to produce the following format (ProductDetail)

```
ID=1,
Name=Chair,
Parent=
{
  { ID=1, Name="Indoor" },
  { ID=2, Name="Outdoor" }
},
Properties { Color="Red", Size="Large" }

ID=2,
Name=Table,
Parent=
{
  { ID=1, Name="Indoor"}
},
Properties { Color = "Blue", Size = "Small" }
```

which we can get the "Color" value of the first item by using

```
ProductDetails[0].Properties.Color
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this based on what you've said - because "Color" and "Size" are part of the *data*, rather than part of the *model*. They're only known at execution time, so unless you use dynamic typing, you're not going to be able to access it by `Properties.Color`.

You could, however, use `Properties["Color"]` potentially:

```
var query = from product in db.Products
            join meta in db.Meta 
                on product.ID equals meta.Object 
                into properties
            select new { Product = product,
                         Properties = properties.ToDictionary(m => m.Key,
                                                              m => m.Value) };
```

So for each product, you'll have a dictionary of properties. That works *logically*, but you may need to tweak it to get it to work in the entity framework - I don't know how well that supports ToDictionary.

EDIT: Okay, I'll leave the above up as the "ideal" solution, but if EF doesn't support ToDictionary, you'd have to do that part in-process:

```
var query = (from product in db.Products
             join meta in db.Meta 
                 on product.ID equals meta.Object 
                 into properties
             select new { product, properties })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(p => new {
                    Product = p.product,
                    Properties = p.properties.ToDictionary(m => m.Key,
                                                           m => m.Value) });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comment but poor EF doesn't support ToDictionary operator T T

Comment: @NVA: In that case you can probably do it using AsEnumerable... editing.

Comment: Thanks again for ur quick reply but when I want to include some extra info from another tables (edited in my post) using join, the generated SQL is too long with a bunch of SELECT ... FROM...Is there a way to clean it up?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question while learning LINQ, but I wasn't satisfied that Jon's output matched the question (sorry Jon). The following code returns a List of anonymously-typed objects that better match the structure of your question:

```
var ProductDetails = (from p in Product
                      let Parents = from r in Relation
                                    where r.ChildID == p.ID
                                    join c in Category on r.ParentID equals c.ID
                                        into RelationCategory
                                    from rc in RelationCategory
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        rc.ID,
                                        rc.Name
                                    }
                      join m in Meta on p.ID equals m.Object into ProductMeta

                      select new
                      {
                          p.ID,
                          p.Name,
                          Parent = Parents.ToList(),
                          ProductMeta
                      })
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(p => new
                     {
                         p.ID,
                         p.Name,
                         p.Parent,
                         Properties = p.ProductMeta
                                       .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value)
                     }).ToList();
```

Credit goes mostly to Jon Skeet and the Visual Studio debugger ;)

I realise that you've probably moved on by now but hopefully this might help someone else looking to learn LINQ, as I was.